# Update PHP code on a server running the Laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel

I am the sole person in charge of a website that keeps track of records that other employees submit and compiles them into nice spreadsheets so that non-technical users can easily read them.

The other guy who used to work here quit unexpectedly, and I have to make a small, one-line change to the PHP code that he wrote, the problem is, when I edit the code, it does not seem to change anything. For example, I can completely delete the code that displays an error message, but that error message will still show up. There are other parts of the  project that I CAN modify, like XML files and python programs, but the PHP does not seem to care if it is modified.

I vaguely remember a command like 'php artisan serve' but that doesn't seem to help either

After googling the problem, I came across several other commands like 'npm run production' and 'php artisan optimise' but those didn't work either.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the code directly on the server? Or are you trying it local first? Is the change on a view-file?
Try `php artisan cache:clear`. It should clear all the caches and probably show your changes.